# How to read in points from a file

Tags: c++

I am reading in a file of the format:

```
12, 10
15, 20
2, 10000
```

I want to read these in as x,y points.  I've started out, but I'm not sure where to proceed from here... Here is what I have so far:

```
ifstream input("points.txt");
string line_data;

while (getline(input, line_data))
{
    int d;
    std::cout << line_data << std::endl;
    stringstream line_stream(line_data);
    while (line_stream >> d)
    {
        std::cout << d << std::endl;
    }
}
```

How can I read each of these lines in as an x,y integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say:

```
int a, b; char comma;

if (line_stream >> a >> comma >> b)
{
  // process pair (a, b)
}
```

Comment: Or, if line-by-line parsing isn't required, `while(input >> a ...) ...`.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, though it's a bit more robust to split it into lines. At least that way you can recover from an error.

Answer (score 2):

what about this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("points.txt");

    while (!input.eof())
    {
        int x, y;
        char separator;

        input >> x  >> separator >> y;

        cout << x << ", " << y << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [This is not a good practice.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `ios::eof` as a loop condition. Doing so almost always results in buggy code. Prefer `while(input >> x >> separator >> y)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ifstream input("points.txt");
int x, y;
char comma;
while (input >> x >> comma >> y)
{
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
}
```